# Error on using SignUpCallback method

Tags: android, parse-platform

I try to use the following code to create new user in my Parse.com but I keep getting the error from my Android Studio:

```
ParseUser newUser=new ParseUser();
newUser.setPassword(password);
newUser.setUsername(username);
newUser.setEmail(email);
newUser.saveInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseException e) {
        if (e==null){
            Intent intent=new Intent(signUpActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }else{
        }
    }
});
```

error is on done() method :

**(10:26) public abstract void done(com.parse.ParseException e); ( method done(ParseException)will have incompatible access privileges with super method SignUpCallback(ParseException))**

Answer (score 1):

to save the sign up object have to use the signUpInBackground() not saveInBackground()